# Brave wallet adapter gives "Signature verification failed"

Tags: signature, solana-wallet-adapter

There is a somewhat new Brave integration in the [@solana-labs/wallet-adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/wallets/brave) and I'm trying to add it to a dApp, but for some reason it throws "Signature verification failed" when trying to execute certain TXs.

Please note that this doesn't happen on all of them and the TXs that can't be signed with Brave can be signed with all the other wallets that I've tried (Phantom, Solflare, Bitkeep, Exodus, Slope, etc).

What can be the difference? Is a problem in the dApp or in the wallet itself?

Comment: Hey Can you share the Transaction object before and after it is signed by Brave Wallet. This way we can debug the difference between the two and find out if the transaction is actually being signed by the brave wallet or not

Comment: Hi, Brave Wallet developer here, as mentioned by @Pratik.js, it would help if you can share the Transaction objects. Also, we recently see a case where dApp wrongly assume wallet would mutate the transaction object they passing in instead of using the one returned by the promise. Please double check it is not the case in your dApp, thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it's quickly becoming a bug report. I've seen instances where – when wallets deserialize and reserialize transaction objects – the transactions change ever so slightly. Sometimes it's a bug with the wallet, but other times it's been due to bugs in web3.js. Can you close this question on Stack Exchange and open a GitHub issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not 'manually' signing the TX. I'm just sending it to be executed. There is no after sign object (unless change code).

Comment: @Jocelyn I don't think it is a problem with the dApp itself as it works with quite a lot of other wallets. There is something specific to Brave which imho it should not be, in order to have the integration as smooth as possible.

Comment: @steveluscher created an issue there: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/478

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like a bug that needs to be addressed on GitHub issues.